# Set new row value on insert from select statement in Oracle SQLplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Is it possible to set a trigger to set the new row's value to be the result of a select statement? My current syntax is as follows and it's just not working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "BRAND_NEW_TRIGGER"
    BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.column_one := (SELECT details_col FROM other_table WHERE property_id = :NEW.property_id);
END;
/
```

I've fudged the details of the code above to protect my company's security, I know the code above doesn't make too much sense but there is a valid reason I need to pull and organise the data this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `select into`

```
select ot.details_col
  into :new.column_one
  from other_table ot
 where ot.property_id = :new.property_id;
```

Of course, I'd strongly question the data model if this makes sense.  That strongly implies that you've got a data model in need of some normalization.